# Parameter "p_control" is null error on removing button from container

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to create a plugin and add a button to the top container like this:

```
tool
extends EditorPlugin

var Btn

func _enter_tree():
    Btn=Button.new();
    Btn.name="Testing_btn"
    Btn.text="Testing";
    Btn.flat=true;
    add_control_to_container(CONTAINER_CANVAS_EDITOR_MENU,Btn);

func _exit_tree():
    remove_control_from_container(CONTAINER_CANVAS_EDITOR_MENU,Btn)
```

but whenever I make changes to the code -> save -> uncheck enabled
[image]

it gives the error:

> editor/editor_plugin.cpp:458 - Parameter "p_control" is null.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the button is being freed or otherwise invalidated before `remove_control_from_container` runs.

I believe you can avoid the error by checking with `is_instance_valid`:

```
func _exit_tree():
    if is_instance_valid(Btn):
        remove_control_from_container(CONTAINER_CANVAS_EDITOR_MENU,Btn)
```